# Trying to post an image in application

Tags: php, mysql, submission

If I submit something to a MySQL database and that object gets an automatic ID assigned, how can I submit data to another table that references this ID?  If the first table auto increments the IDs for new records, I can make a call to get the max ID of that table after submission - but this seems pretty hacky and prone to errors should multiple users be on the same application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is a little unclear, but what I think you need is `mysql_insert_id()`, it will return the id of the last inserted row using `mysql_query`.

Example:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `journal_post` (...) VALUES (...)"); //Insert proper code in ...
$pid = mysql_insert_id(); //Contains the ID of the just inserted journal_post
if (...) { //Some check to see if an image was attached
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `img_details` (...) VALUES (...)");
}
```

If this is not what you meant, please provide a code sample to elaborate the problem.

Comment: You should click on the checkmark next to the answer then, so other users can see it has been answered.

Comment: OK - new to this site and was wondering how to select your answer.  Thanks again!